# Auto update mysql table each time a row its added to another table

Tags: mysql, auto-update

The problem i need to solve is the following:

I have an "incomes" table where rows are added for each income, and every income has a price.

I also have another table called "months" with a column called "total_income".

The "incomes" table has a column called "id_month" to link both tables.

Whats the most efficient way to update the "total_income" column each time a row is added to the "incomes" table??

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: Search for "mysql triggers". And try something and if you can't get it to work, add the code you have tried here as @SuperBiasedMan suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies :) I was posting in order to know whats the most efficient way to this before trying to test code.. Do yoy recommend triggers better than updating the column each time there is an insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is you are having 2 tables. 
1) Incomes Table 2) Months Table

**Incomes Table**

### id_month | Income

**Month Table**

### id_month | Total_Income

So, when you are inserting row in 'incomes' table.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO incomes SET id_month='$Month', Income='$Income'");
```

After Inserting, calculate 'total income' from months table for that particular table.

```
$TotalIncome=0;
$Query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM months WHERE id_month='$month'");
while($RowQ=mysql_fetch_array($Query))
{
   $IncomeAvailable=$RowQ['Total_Income'];
}

After That, $TotalIncome=$IncomeAvailable+$Income; 

mysql_query("UPDATE months SET Total_Income='$TotalIncome' WHERE id_month='$month'");
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than triggers?

Comment: no, this can't be efficient than triggers. Triggers are best one to use.